# <jdbc:initialize-database> is not working

Tags: mysql, spring

Hi guys I have simple mysql script here it is.

```
delimiter $$
use ta

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS bin2uuid;
CREATE FUNCTION bin2uuid(bin BINARY(16)) RETURNS char(36) CHARSET utf8
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE hex CHAR(32);
  IF(bin IS NULL) THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  ELSE
    SET hex = HEX(bin);
    RETURN LOWER(CONCAT(LEFT(hex, 8),'-'
                          ,SUBSTR(hex, 9,4),'-'
                          ,SUBSTR(hex,13,4),'-'
                          ,SUBSTR(hex,17,4),'-'
                          ,RIGHT(hex, 12)
                          ));
  END IF;
END;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS uuid2bin;

CREATE FUNCTION `uuid2bin`(guid CHAR(36))
   RETURNS binary(16)
   DETERMINISTIC
   BEGIN
      IF (guid IS NULL)
      THEN
         RETURN NULL;
      ELSE
         SET @newguid = IFNULL(guid, UUID());
         RETURN UNHEX(REPLACE(@newguid, '-', ''));
      END IF;
   END;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS calcAllocTradPartyName;   

CREATE FUNCTION calcAllocTradPartyName(vTradeId varchar(36))
  RETURNS varchar(200)
  BEGIN
    DECLARE pTradingPartName varchar(200);

  SELECT
    IF(tpo.broker = 1,IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  IFNULL(tp.symbol,otp.name) SEPARATOR ', '),'TRADAIR'),tpo.name) INTO pTradingPartName
    FROM trades t
    INNER JOIN orderslogadd o ON t.orderId = o.orderId
    INNER JOIN users u ON o.userId = u.guid
    LEFT JOIN orgs tpo ON u.orgId = tpo.guid
    LEFT JOIN tradesAlloc tra ON t.guid = tra.tradeId
    LEFT JOIN tradingparty tp ON tra.tradingpartyId = tp.id
    LEFT JOIN orgs otp ON tra.tradingpartyId = otp.guid
    WHERE t.guid = uuid2bin(vTradeId);

  RETURN pTradingPartName;
  END;   


$$
```

Here is a part of my `app-context.xml` that initializes the database. The problem is that when i run the script in mysql or in TOAD it works fine but when Spring tries to run it  gives me the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE FUNCTION bin2uuid(bin BINARY(16)) RETURNS char(36) CHARSET utf8     DETER' at line 1
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter' at line 1
```

I tried to run it with out a delimiter `$$` word but then it fails on this exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS bin2uuid; CREATE FUNCTION bin2uuid(bin BINARY(16)) RETUR' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your configuration but I'm guessing you need to tell Spring about the separator too (there is no standard SQL script statement separator).  the  element has a separator attribute for that purpose.